# numpy.ndarray sent as argument doesn't need loop for iteration?

Tags: python, numpy, arguments

In this code `np.linspace()` assigns to `inputs` 200 evenly spaced numbers from -20 to 20.

This function works. What I am not understanding is how could it work. How can `inputs` be sent as an argument to `output_function()` without needing a loop to iterate over the numpy.ndarray?

```
def output_function(x):
    return 100 - x ** 2

inputs = np.linspace(-20, 20, 200)
plt.plot(inputs, output_function(inputs), 'b-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is `numpy.vectorize` which behaves similarly to the python builtin `map`.

Here is one way you can use `numpy.vectorize`:

```
outputs = (np.vectorize(output_function))(inputs)
```

---

You asked why it worked, it works because numpy arrays can perform operations on its array elements en masse, for example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]) # gives you a numpy array of 4 elements [1,2,3,4]
b = a - 1 # this operation on a numpy array will subtract 1 from every element resulting in the array [0,1,2,3]
```

Because of this property of numpy arrays you can perform certain operations on **every element** of a numpy array very quickly without using a loop (like what you would do if it were a regular python array).

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question for clarity -- my code works, I'm just not understanding how.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully answer your original question a little bit better

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` works by defining operations on vectors the way that you really want to work with them mathematically.  So, I can do something like:

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(10)
c = a + b
```

And it works as you might hope -- each element of `a` is added to the corresponding element of `b` and the result is stored in a new array `c`.  If you want to know *how* numpy  accomplishes this, it's all done via the magic methods in the python data model.  Specifically in my example case, the `__add__` method of numpy's `ndarray` would be overridden to provide the desired behavior.